# .net MAUI Picker SelectedIndex does not cause item to display

Tags: maui, picker, selectedindex

I cannot get the expected behaviour of SelectedIndex to work. The Item is not shown. The ItemSource, ItemDisplayBinding and SelectedItem are working when the picker is selected, But when the view is first displayed the Pickers are not showing the objects from the List that they are bound to.

I have created a test .Maui APP as follows;

The View MainPage.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
            xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MauiPicker;assembly=MauiPicker"
            xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MauiPicker"
             x:Class="MauiPicker.MainPage"
             x:DataType="viewModels:MainViewModel">

    <Grid
        ColumnDefinitions="*"
        RowDefinitions="*,*">
        <CollectionView
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PartAResultLists}"
            SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:PartAResultList">
                        <Grid Padding="5">
                            <Border>
                                <Grid Padding="10"
                                    ColumnDefinitions="Auto,*"
                                    RowDefinitions="Auto"
                                    RowSpacing="7">
                                    <Label Text="Outlet Type:" 
                                            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                                    <Border
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                        <Picker
                                            Title="Select an Outlet"
                                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:MainViewModel}},                                   Path=Outlets}"
                                            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}"
                                            SelectedIndex="{Binding OutletIndex}"
                                            SelectedItem="{Binding OutletName}">
                                        </Picker>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Text="Reload List"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewModels:MainViewModel}}, Path=LoadResultsCommand}">
        </Button>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

The code behind MainPage.xml.cs

```
        namespace MauiPicker;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

The ViewModel MainViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using MvvmHelpers;

namespace MauiPicker
{
    public partial class MainViewModel : CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.ObservableObject
    {

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            LoadResults();
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        async Task LoadResults()
        {

            Outlets = new ObservableRangeCollection<Outlet>
            {
                new Outlet(){Name="Outlet0"},
                new Outlet(){Name="Outlet1"},
                new Outlet(){Name="Outlet2"},

            };


            PartAResultLists = new ObservableRangeCollection<PartAResultList>
            {
                new PartAResultList(){OutletIndex = 0, OutletName= new Outlet(){Name="Outlet0" } },
                new PartAResultList(){OutletIndex=1, OutletName= new Outlet(){Name="Outlet1" }},
                new PartAResultList(){OutletIndex = 2, OutletName= new Outlet(){Name="Outlet2" }},
                new PartAResultList(){OutletIndex = 0, OutletName= new Outlet(){Name="Outlet0" }},
                new PartAResultList(){OutletIndex = 2, OutletName= new Outlet(){Name="Outlet2" }}
            };
        }


        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableRangeCollection<Outlet> outlets;

        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableRangeCollection<PartAResultList> partAResultLists;

    }
}
```

The models;

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace MauiPicker
{
    public partial class Outlet : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string name;
    }
}
```

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace MauiPicker
{
    public partial class PartAResultList : ObservableObject
    {

        [ObservableProperty]
        public Outlet outletName;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public int outletIndex;

    }
}
```

MauiProgram.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MauiPicker;

public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. In the title you say in Picker, but from the code I found out that it is in `CollectionView`. Can you elaborate on what you want to achieve? And could you please post a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: `I cut and paste the SelectedIndex xml line and paste it in say one line up the Items appear in the View, but if I spin up the app again the Item is not displayed`  I don't quite understand the meaning of above words. Can you explain in detail?

Comment: Just because you are using ObservableObject, it does not mean that properties are observable. Use fields instead, and annotate them with [ObservableProperty]. (Along with other fixes of that code.) I wont even comment on this: "I have tried changing the order of ItemSource, SelectedIndex and SelectedItem". Just don't.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I left out the opening <Picker xaml. I ve put it back. sorry for type

Comment: @H.A.H.  I annotated the fields in the PartAResultList model as follows;
  [ObservableProperty]
  int testPropertyIndex;

Still no update of Picker. Thought it would work as I remember now I had to do this in another view, but still no change.

The old way also did not fix the problem

  private int testPropertyIndex;
        public int TestPropertyIndex
        {
            get => testPropertyIndex;
            set => SetProperty(ref testPropertyIndex, value);
        }

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Jessie when in hot reload if I cut the line SelectedIndex={Binding=TestPropertyIndex and paste say 1 line up then the Picker shows the ItemDisplayBinding correct item. Not sure if it indicates anything about the problem though but was just an observation

Comment: @scott then update your code to show the change. Also: [ObservableProperty]
        List<PartAResultList> partAResultLists; is this the way to make observable collection?

Comment: @H.A.H. I changed List<> to ObservableRangeCollection<> but still not showing the Item. I have checked the data in the resultant tables and the values in selectedindex, seecteditem match back to the database. SelectedIndex is an int=2 and selecteditem is of type Outlet and this object contains the correct values. I will create a sample todo with this code and see if the problem is reproduced

Comment: @H.A.H.   I have replaced the code now with a working example. This reproduces the problem. As I mentioned earlier when in hot reload you can cut and paste the xml SelectedIndex line in the picker control and paste it back in and the control refreshes and correctly displays the items. This suggests to me there is an issue with INotify property or Binding perhaps?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT There is a sample code now above to test

Comment: @scott What selected index?! SelectionMode="None">

Comment: @H.A.H. SelectedIndex is on the Picker control. SelectionMode is on the CollectionView so I am not sure I follow your comment. I removed selectionmode anyway but no affect. Did you give the sample app a try?

Comment: I have posted a new Maui issue to see if anyone can find the problem with my code or if its a bug

Comment: @H.A.H. Hello H.A.H any further thoughts?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Hello Jessie Zhang any further thoughts?

Comment: @scott My thoughts are that you have to clear this mess. This here:  new Outlet(){Name="Outlet0"}, and this here: OutletName= new Outlet(){Name="Outlet0" are two completely different objects. How do you know the program will know they are equal? I do not know why you are using two different models, two different properties, and at the same time Selected Item and Index. And last, I want to point out, that events are triggered only if the last value is not equal to the new assigned value. You can see this in the autogenerated code of MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I want to point out, for anyone who is reading this, that the code in the question is bound correctly.

Second, I want to say that new Outlet(Name="1") and new Outlet(Name="1") are not equal. Just because some property has the same value, does not mean that the objects will be the same. They are saved at two different places, and they are not the same. Not unless you make sure that only "Name" matters, when checking if they are equal.

Third, If you check the community toolkit MVVM autogenerated property code, you will see something like:

```
if(!global::System.Collections.Generic.EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(name, value))
```

And calling OnChanged in that IF block. This is optimization to help only waste resources, when something has to be re-rendered.

This is why, when you set:

```
new PartAResultList(){OutletIndex = 0...
```

And then if you call, for example:

```
PartAResultLists[0].OutletIndex = 0;
```

The picker will remain blank. But if you call this:

```
PartAResultLists[0].OutletIndex = 1;
```

Surprisingly it will change.
(Again, giving example with the index, because the object will not work for the reasons I pointed out earlier).

There is no need to bind to Object and to Index at the same time. In your situation this can only lead to more bugs.

Your bindings are setup well. You have to fix your code around them here and there.

Edit: You do not have to actually change the value. Just trying to explain the problem that OnPropertyChanged("OutletIndex") is not called.

Theoretical example: Lets say that in the:

```
public partial class PartAResultList : ObservableObject
```

We place some method:

```
NotifyWorkaround(){
      OnPropertyChanged("OutletIndex");
}
```

We can now call PartAResultList[n].NotifyWorkaround(), for every n-th element of the list. And the interface will respond to the change.

I have never used this in production however. It worked for your example (I added 10 elements), but I have no idea what impact it will have on 1000, 10k, or more elements in the list.

Comment: thanks @H.A.H. I had suspected but testing in way you mention updates the UI. I will explore how I can trigger onpropertychanged so they update showing the data from the model when the page appears

Comment: would you mind providing a bit more help as I am still unable to trigger the onpropertychanged event to update the view.

Comment: @scott Just tested it with OnPropertyChanged("OutletIndex"); It gets shown in the picker immediately.

Comment: awfully sorry but can you show me where you place OnPropertyChanged("OutletIndex"); ? I place it in varioius places but nothing happens even though it gets hit

Comment: @scott there is only one place where you can put it. This is the PartAResultList class. It is the owner of this property, and is observable object.

Comment: Added some clarification. This notification should be called at later time, after the elements are loaded in the interface.

Comment: I have not been able to find anywhere to call this workaround that occurs after the UI is loaded so I have added a Task Delay and then perform the workaround. I think this is a MAUI bug at this stage because it should be more elegantly handled than this. It shoudl be built in when a UI is laoded with its model prepopulated with values for a Picker. await Task.Delay(3000);
    for (int i = 0; i < PartAResultLists.Count; i++)
     PartAResultLists[i].NotifyWorkaround();

Comment: @scott I had limited success with those workarounds. I have been setting value to something that they never can be (for example, apples count = -1) so that the change gets detected the first time the value is set to something useful. I have also used various events (On Appearing for example) and task scheduling one after another. However, I do not recommend those workarounds for getting anywhere near production code. I am sorry that I cannot be more helpful. Its just that I am in the same swamp that you are.

Comment: Dont worry HAH you are awesome. They will slowly fix all the MAUI bugs